# handling an Array of objects

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array of objects each object contains a MySQL database row that also contains information about an item. my question is how can I get a certain key-value from an object depending on another key? let me get it straight, `items` is a `JSON` array contains a couple of objects each object is generated with both numeric and string `keys`, So what I need is to get the value of the `price` key that in the same Object with a specific `codenumber` basically getting the `price` value from the `codenumber` key
the Second thing is how to add a new key within a new value to the object? like if I have a variable called `$Count` how can I add his value to the object within a new key like `Count`? is the function array_push can add a new key to the Object?

the `JSON` array

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => o4
        [2] => Efexor
        [3] => Eklil
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 30
        [6] => 15
        [7] => Phezer
        [8] => Venlafaxine
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-08-25
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [id] => 1
        [qty] => 15
        [Sale] => 1
        [name] => Efexor
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 30
        [company] => Phezer
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [owned-com] => Eklil
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] => o4
        [chemicalcom] => Venlafaxine
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 2021-08-25
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
 )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 2
        [1] =>
        [2] => Efexor
        [3] => Eklil
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 15
        [6] => 10
        [7] => Phezer
        [8] => Venlafaxine
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-08-25
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [id] => 2
        [qty] => 10
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] => Efexor
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 15
        [company] => Phezer
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\Efexor.jpg
        [owned-com] => Eklil
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] => Venlafaxine
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 2021-08-25
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 3
        [1] =>
        [2] => panadol
        [3] => com2
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 5
        [6] => 12
        [7] => GSK
        [8] => Paracetamol
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 2020-04-09
        [12] => 2021-02-09
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 2
        [16] => taps
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 3
        [qty] => 12
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] => panadol
        [bonus] => 2
        [price] => 5
        [company] => GSK
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] => com2
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] => Paracetamol
        [dosage-form] => taps
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 2021-02-09
        [production-date] => 2020-04-09
    )
    [3] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => codenumber
        [2] => name
        [3] => owned
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 9
        [6] => 1
        [7] => gsk
        [8] => gscom
        [9] => 12mg
        [10] => 3
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-02-09
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 4
        [qty] => 1
        [Sale] => 1
        [name] => name
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 9
        [company] => gsk
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] => owned
        [pack-size] => 3
        [codenumber] => codenumber
        [chemicalcom] => gscom
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] => 12mg
        [expiration-date] => 2021-02-09
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
    )
    [4] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => d322
        [2] => fsdfds
        [3] => ewfwef
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 3232
        [6] => 222
        [7] => none
        [8] => nonoe
        [9] => nonoe
        [10] => 12
        [11] => 2020-03-25
        [12] => 2021-02-09
        [13] => 1
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 2
        [16] => caps
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 5
        [qty] => 222
        [Sale] => 1
        [name] => fsdfds
        [bonus] => 2
        [price] => 3232
        [company] => none
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] => ewfwef
        [pack-size] => 12
        [codenumber] => d322
        [chemicalcom] => nonoe
        [dosage-form] => caps
        [concentration] => nonoe
        [expiration-date] => 2021-02-09
        [production-date] => 2020-03-25
    )
    [5] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 6
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] =>
        [8] =>
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0000-00-00
        [12] => 0000-00-00
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => eyedrop
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 6
        [qty] => 0
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] =>
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 0
        [company] =>
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] =>
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] =>
        [dosage-form] => eyedrop
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 0000-00-00
        [production-date] => 0000-00-00
    )
    [6] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 7
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] =>
        [8] =>
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0000-00-00
        [12] => 0000-00-00
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] =>
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 7
        [qty] => 0
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] =>
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 0
        [company] =>
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] =>
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] =>
        [dosage-form] =>
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 0000-00-00
        [production-date] => 0000-00-00
    )
    [7] => stdClass Object (
        [0] => 8
        [1] =>
        [2] =>
        [3] =>
        [4] => 1
        [5] => 0
        [6] => 0
        [7] =>
        [8] =>
        [9] =>
        [10] => 0
        [11] => 0000-00-00
        [12] => 0000-00-00
        [13] => 0
        [14] => 0
        [15] => 0
        [16] => eardrop
        [17] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [id] => 8
        [qty] => 0
        [Sale] => 0
        [name] =>
        [bonus] => 0
        [price] => 0
        [company] =>
        [draftid] => 1
        [discount] => 0
        [imageurl] => ..\upload\panadol.png
        [owned-com] =>
        [pack-size] => 0
        [codenumber] =>
        [chemicalcom] =>
        [dosage-form] => eardrop
        [concentration] =>
        [expiration-date] => 0000-00-00
        [production-date] => 0000-00-00
    )
)
```

my attempt to make the first function `core.php`:-

```
<?PHP
 public function getPrice($id,$codenumber){
        if($this->connected === true){
            try{
                $items = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT `items` FROM `bills` WHERE id=:id");
                $items->bindParam(":id",$id);
                $items->execute();
                $fetchedItems = $items->fetchColumn();
                $items = json_decode($fetchedItems);
                foreach ($items as $item){
                    $price = $item->price;
                    echo $price; // What i want is to echo the Price-Key for the value that has the $codenumber [key]
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                if($this->errors === true){
                    return $this->error($e->getMessage());
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `codenumber` is unique in the array, just re-index your array with `codenumber` and then it's simple  (PHP >= 7):

```
$codenumber = 'o4';
$array = array_column($array, null, 'codenumber');
echo $array[$codenumber]->price;  // outputs 30
```

That's reusable multiple times.  If you just need to do it once:

```
echo array_column($array, null, 'codenumber')[$codenumber]->price;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my problem solved and the code is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this, where $id is the value you are searching for and $json is your array. If count doesn't exist, it will automatically be created with a value of 0.

```
$id = 100;
$items = json_decode($fetchedItems, true);
foreach($items as $k => $v){
   if(isset($json[$k]["count"]) === false){
      $json[$k]["count"] = 0;
   }

   if($v["codenumber"] == $id){
      $json[$k]["count"] += $v["price"];
   }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work I tried to manipulate around the code but I get `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` FYI the `JSON` array is decoded before looping foreach and the second code block, to be honest, I didn't understand it

Comment: @MrObscure I made a change, I added true to json_decode so it converts it into an array.